# custom environment that mimics gather or align

Tags: environments

I guess I want to define a new environment, but perhaps it already exists and I didn't know what to search for.

The environment I want should leave the equations center aligned if no `&` is present and should keep the `=` signs aligned if present.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{customEnv}%behave like gather
   a=1,\\
   b=1111111111111111111111111111.
\end{customEnv}

\begin{customEnv}%behave like align
   a&=1,\\
   b&=1111111111111111111111111111.
\end{customEnv}

\end{document}
```

PS: Bonus points if we can use some parameter to change the environment's behavior when without `&`, so that it defaults to center, left or right depending on this parameter!!!

PPS: If possible try to use only the standar packages available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you gain something? I'm not. For instance, you give up being able to nest `align` or `aligned` in `gather`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse,environ}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewEnviron{customEnv}
 {
  \tl_if_in:NnTF \BODY { & }
   {
    \begin{align}\BODY\end{align}
   }
   {
    \begin{gather}\BODY\end{gather}
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{customEnv}%behave like gather
   a=1,\\
   b=1111111111111111111111111111.
\end{customEnv}

\begin{customEnv}%behave like align
   a&=1,\\
   b&=1111111111111111111111111111.
\end{customEnv}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am a new user and so far have not had the need to nest `align` with `gather`. Do you see that often?

Answer (score 1):

Here, I use TABstacks.  I use the `\readTABstack` feature to absorb the data and analyze the input.  The `\TABcells` feature to tell me how many columns there are in row 1.  If 1, I use a `\Centerstack`, else an `\alignCenterstack`.

However, I must add the disclaimer that a TABstack will not number each equation uniquely.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\newcommand\mystack[2][c]{%
  \readTABstack{#2}%
  \ifnum\TABcells{1}=1\relax%
    \Centerstack[#1]{#2}%
  \else%
    \alignCenterstack{#2}%
  \fi%
}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\[\mystack[l]{%behave like gather
   W=1,\\
   b=1111111111111111111111111111.
}\]
\[\mystack[c]{%behave like gather
   W=1,\\
   b=1111111111111111111111111111.
}\]
\[\mystack[r]{%behave like gather
   W=1,\\
   b=1111111111111111111111111111.
}\]
\[\mystack{%behave like align
   W=&1,\\
   b=&1111111111111111111111111111.
}\]
\end{document}
```

In the above MWE, three separately aligned (left, center, right) non-tabbed stacks are shown, followed by the input using aligning tabs.

[image]

Comment: your result is exactly what I want, but unfortunately the package is not recognized on my PC nor on sharelatex. It could cause some problems when collaborating. I will update the question.

Comment: @ivbc http://ctan.org/pkg/tabstackengine